# How to explain "Liberty Mutual" company name?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I was asked by a friend of mine to translate/explain:

> Liberty Mutual

company name. *Liberty* means *freedom* and what does *mutual* mean in the context?

I have a hypotesis of it's being *mutual fund* or *mutual insurance*, but not sure.

**P.S.** I am not in any way related to the company nor this question was created for promotion purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a snippet from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_organization):

> A **mutual**, **mutual organization**, or **mutual society** is an organization (which is often, but not always, a company or business) based on the principle of mutuality. Unlike a true cooperative, members usually do not contribute to the capital of the company by direct investment, but derive their right to profits and votes through their customer relationship. A mutual organization or society is often simply referred to as a *mutual*.
>
> A mutual exists with the purpose of raising funds from its membership or customers (collectively called its *members*), which can then be used to provide common services to all members of the organization or society. A mutual is therefore owned by, and run for the benefit of, its members - it has no external shareholders to pay in the form of dividends, and as such does not usually seek to maximize and make large profits or capital gains. Mutuals exist for the members to benefit from the services they provide and often do not pay income tax.
>
> Profits made will usually be re-invested in the mutual for the benefit of the members, although some profit may also be necessary in the case of mutuals for internal financing to sustain or grow the organization, and to make sure it remains safe and secure.

Liberty Mutual is an insurance company that provides liberty (in finances) and is a mutual organization.